# Creating custom Color for UIColor

Tags: swift, uicolor

I have a question about creating a custom UIColor in swift.

I used the following extension code:

```
import UIKit

extension UIColor {
  convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
    let newRed = CGFloat(red)/255
    let newGreen = CGFloat(green)/255
    let newBlue = CGFloat(blue)/255

    self.init(red: newRed, green: newGreen, blue: newBlue, alpha: 1.0)


    }
}

let brandBlue = UIColor(red: 0, green: 127, blue: 255)
```

I want to load it in, shadowColor, under the following code:

```
class squareButton : UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        self.layer.shadowColor = (Loading code here)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.5
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false   
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        self.layer.shadowColor = (Loading code here)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.5
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false  
    }
}
```

But every combination I used won't work. Every time it says that I should use as! CGColor but when I do that, the app crashes.

Please help me

Thank you

Comment: do you need further help on this topic? If it was helpful it would be great, if you can mark my answer as the correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you are currently providing to `self.layer.shadowColor = (Loading code here)` a `UIColor` this should cause a compiler error.

The extension you created is fine. Just use the `.cgColor` property of `UIColor` after you instantiated your new `UIColor` instance. This would then be the example code:

```
class SquareButton: UIButton {

    let brandBlue: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 127, blue: 255)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        self.layer.shadowColor = brandBlue.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.5
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false   
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        self.layer.shadowColor = brandBlue.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.5
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`CGColor` and `UIColor`are not the same and `CALayer.shadowColor` needs to be a `CGColor`. You can get a `CGColor` from a `UIColor` by calling the `cgColor` property on a `UIColor` instance.

Like this: `self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 127, blue: 255).cgColor`